# mvc4 dropdownlistfor databinds with Post, but not with Ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http-post, bind, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a DropDowListFor in a table row, in a form.  If I submit the form with HttpPost, the dropdownlist databinds to my ViewModel with the correct values for every row.  But, if I do an ajax call rather than a submit, the databinding only works for the first row but not for the subsequent rows, which are all null.
My PartialView (which sits inside a Html.BeginForm) is like this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.FilterConditionsIsBoolTrue[i]
      , new [] { new SelectListItem { Text = "True", Value="true" } , new SelectListItem { Text = "False", Value="false"} }
      , new { @class = "isbooldropdown" })
```

My Ajax call is:

```
$('#btnRun').click(function () {
var form = $("#CriteriaFormId");
$.ajax({
    url: "/Screener/PostFilterResults",
    data: form.serialize(),
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (myResult) {
        $('#resultstable').html(myResult);
    }
  })
});
```

and my ViewModel:

```
public class FilterVM
{
    public FilterVM(GenesisFT.WebApps.Models.Filter filter, List<FilterConditionDefinition> fcd)
    {
        gftFilter = filter;
        FilterConditionDefinitions = fcd;

        foreach (FilterConditionDefinition filterConditionDefinition in FilterConditionDefinitions)
        {

        // TEST
        FilterConditionsIsBoolTrue = new string[50];
        for (int i = 0; i < FilterConditionsIsBoolTrue.Length; i++)
        {
            FilterConditionsIsBoolTrue[i] = "true";
        }
    }
    public string[] FilterConditionsIsBoolTrue { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I am still in need.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I am still stuck on this.  Is there somewhere else where I might try to get an answer to this question?